# how auth token flow can be handled in java using gmail api call

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, gmail-api, google-api-java-client

.I want to integrate whole gmail functionalities like read, list, send using myApp. I have tried using http://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token HTTP/1.1
but couldn't get access token. Kindly provide flow.

Tried using POST : http://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token HTTP/1.1 and POST : https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token though getting error 404 not found.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you have so that we can try and get it reopened.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consult [Java Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java)  It contains a full authorization example.

```
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.Gmail;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.GmailScopes;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.model.Label;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.model.ListLabelsResponse;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class GmailQuickstart {
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Gmail API Java Quickstart";
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    private static final String TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH = "tokens";

    /**
     * Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
     * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved tokens/ folder.
     */
    private static final List<String> SCOPES = Collections.singletonList(GmailScopes.GMAIL_LABELS);
    private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/credentials.json";

    /**
     * Creates an authorized Credential object.
     * @param HTTP_TRANSPORT The network HTTP Transport.
     * @return An authorized Credential object.
     * @throws IOException If the credentials.json file cannot be found.
     */
    private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws IOException {
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in = GmailQuickstart.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        if (in == null) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        }
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .build();
        LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
        return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        // Build a new authorized API client service.
        final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        Gmail service = new Gmail.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();

        // Print the labels in the user's account.
        String user = "me";
        ListLabelsResponse listResponse = service.users().labels().list(user).execute();
        List<Label> labels = listResponse.getLabels();
        if (labels.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("No labels found.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Labels:");
            for (Label label : labels) {
                System.out.printf("- %s\n", label.getName());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## application verification

Remember gmail scopes are considered to be the most sensitive. You should consider submitting your application now for verification as it can take time to go though the process.  Also remember you may be charged for the verification of a gmail scope because the review is done by a third party and not google themselves.

Comment: I could not understand your way of solution. I want to get token using http://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token is there a way ?@DaImTo

Comment: @Sa1 The token is processed in the code, the quickstart provided in the answer is what you need to set the code with a token, you don't need securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token

Comment: Secure token is part of firebase.   You should use the **Official** google client library for working with this api .   Try following the quick start.